# Group by in pandas dataframe and unioning a numpy array column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a CSV file where one of the columns looks like a numpy array. The first few lines look like the following

```
first,second,third
170.0,2,[19 234 376]
170.0,3,[19 23 23]
162.0,4,[1 2 3]
162.0,5,[1 3 4]
```

When I load the this CSV with pandas data frame and using the following code

```
data = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', converters = {'first': np.float64, 'second': np.int64, 'third': np.array})
```

Now, I want to group by based on the 'first' column and union the 'third' column. So after doing this my dataframe should look like

```
170.0, [19 23 234 376]
162.0, [1 2 3 4]
```

How do I achieve this? I tried multiple ways like the following and nothing seems to help achieve this goal.

```
group_data = data.groupby('first')
group_data['third'].apply(lambda x: np.unique(np.concatenate(x)))
```

Comment: Are you sure your second column is a np array? when I run your code I get `object` as the `dtype` which indicates to me it's in fact a string., can you post the output from `data.info()` and also `data['second'].iloc[0]`

Comment: Yes, you are right it is loaded as an object. Here is how it looks like

<br/>

    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Int64Index: 4 entries, 0 to 3
    Data columns (total 2 columns):
    first     4 non-null float64
    second    4 non-null object
    dtypes: float64(1), object(1)

<br/>

How do I load them as numpy arrays?

Comment: Try this: `data = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', header=None, names=['first','second'], converters = {'first': np.float64, 'second': np.array})` The problem with your code is that your file does not have any header names so your converters will not find a match

Comment: Sorry! I have corrected the original question. My file did have column names as the first line.

Comment: Well you have inconsistent separators, some lines have spaces others don't as well as commas, is this correct?

Comment: Again my bad! These inconsistency are because of the copy paste. I have corrected question again, the file has exactly like the one here.

Comment: You inserted a new 'second' column, moving the old 'second' column to 'third'.  You have to edit the rest of your question to match the new column names - especially what you are now using for converters.

Comment: Corrected the entire question. Can you someone help me convert this array column to a numpy array and do a groupby union?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current csv file the 'third' column comes in as a string, instead of a list.

There might be nicer ways to convert to a list, but here goes...

```
from ast import literal_eval

data = pd.read_csv('test_groupby.csv')

# Convert to a string representation of a list...
data['third'] = data['third'].str.replace(' ', ',')

# Convert string to list...
data['third'] = data['third'].apply(literal_eval)

group_data=data.groupby('first')

# Two secrets here revealed
# x.values instead of x since x is a Series
# list(...) to return an aggregated value
#     (np.array should work here, but...?)
ans = group_data.aggregate(
      {'third': lambda x: list(np.unique(
                               np.concatenate(x.values)))})

print(ans)
                    third
first                    
162          [1, 2, 3, 4]
170    [19, 23, 234, 376]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That works well! Thanks for literal_eval, which is the key!